# Chronoforms display List of "Client Details" where Current Logged in User created them

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have created 2 chronoforms, one where the logged in user creates reacords of their clients, the second is a form that shows a list of those clients and their details to the same logged in user.

This is the code I have placed in the Custom Code Chronoforms Element:

```
    <?php 
    defined('_JEXEC') or die();
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $usr_id = $user->get('id');
    $usr_name = $user->get('name');
    echo $usr_id;
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM crd_chronoforms_data_RepsClient WHERE cf_created_by = '$usr_id'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $data = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach($form->data['crdchronoformsdataRepsClient'] as $detail);

    ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
<th>Client</th>
<th>Contact Name</th>
<th>Contact Number</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo  $detail['cf_rep_client'];?></td>
<td><?php echo  $detail['cf_rep_contact'];?></td>
<td><?php echo  $detail['cf_rep_tel'];?></td>
<td><a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=reps_clients&token=<?php echo $detail['cf_uid'];?>">Edit</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

However, at present, all the list is showing is the Logged in users ID# i.e.

> echo $usr_id;

I don't know where my syntax has bombed out. Any help and fresh eyes are appreciated.

---

New Error now ...

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/cardosoc/public_html/administrator/components/com_chronoforms/form_actions/custom_code/custom_code.php(19) : eval()'d code on line 26

```
       <?php
   $user = JFactory::getUser();
   $usr_id = $user->id;
   $usr_name = $user->username;
   echo $usr_name;

   $db = JFactory::getDBO();
   $query = $db->getQuery(true);   
   $query->select('*')
    ->from('#__chronoforms_data_RepsClient')
    ->where('cf_created_by ='. $usr_id);   
   $db->setQuery($query);
   $data = $db->loadObjectList();

   foreach($data as $detail): 
   ?>
   <table>
       <tr>
    <th>Client</th>
    <th>Contact Name</th>
    <th>Contact Number</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>    
   </tr>
       <tr>
    <td><?php echo $detail['rep_client'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $detail['rep_contact'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $detail['rep_tel'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $detail['rep_client_address'];?></td>
    <td><a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=reps_clients&token=<?php echo $detail['cf_uid'];?>">Edit</td>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
       </tr>
   </table>
```

HOWEVER ... if I change the

> foreach($data as $detail): 
>   TO
>   foreach($db as $detail):

I get a response of

```
m m m m
```

Comment: foreach($form->data['crdchronoformsdataRepsClient'] as $details);

Comment: Saw the `$details` and changed it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this which uses Joomla 2.5 coding standards + a few changes:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->id;
$usr_name = $user->username;
echo $usr_id;

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);   
$query->select('*')
      ->from('#__crd_chronoforms_data_RepsClient')
      ->where('cf_created_by = ' . $usr_id);   
$db->setQuery($query);
$data = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($data as $detail) : ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Contact Name</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $detail['cf_rep_client'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detail['cf_rep_contact'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detail['cf_rep_tel'];?></td>
        <td><a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=reps_clients&token=<?php echo $detail['cf_uid'];?>">Edit</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You weren't defining the database table correctly either. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi Lodder
I gave it a shot, and it looks lik eit may work, but throws errors when I try to use the `foreach` and or `?php echo  $detail['` etc. I ahve tried various different things, I tried dropping the `foreach` statement and instead of `$detail` I have tried `$db` and `$query` .. but that still throws out errors. Thanks again for your input, I appreciate it!

Comment: @user1395580 - I have updated my answer with the full code. Have a try of it and let me know

Comment: Hi Lodder I gave it a try, it works somewhat if I change the `$data` to `$db` for some reason ?